# Где находится нулевой байт в конце строки string[100]?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{
char string[100]; 
int number; 
printf("Variant 9\n"); 
scanf("%s %i", string, &number);
printf("%i %s", number, string); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Если `scanf` считает `n` символов, то в массив `string` она запишет `n+1` символ. Последний записанный символ и будет нулевой символ.

Answer (score 2):

Вот здесь:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()  {
    char string[100]; 
    int number, pos; 
    
    printf("Variant 9\n"); 
    scanf("%s %i", string, &number);
    printf("%i %s\n", number, string); 

    pos = strlen(string);
    printf("Нулевой байт: %02x в позиции %d\n", string[pos], pos);
    return 0;
}
```

Поэкспериментируйте со строками  разной длины.